# This knob is not updating and i don't know why

Tags: javascript, php, html

In my php i have this:

```
<?php
@include_once('fields.php');
$gg = fetchinfo("val","inf","n","current");
$mm = fetchinfo("val","info","n","max");
$cc = fetchinfo("num","games","id",$gg);

$percent = $cc / $mm *100;


echo'<input class="knob" id="progress-circle" data-fgcolor="#f15700" data-bgcolor="rgba(23,28,34,0.8)" data-min="'.$cc.'" data-max="'.$mm.'" data-thickness=".2" readonly="readonly" value="'.$cc.'" data-width="18%" style="width: 142px; height: 92px; position: absolute; vertical-align: middle; margin-top: 92px; margin-left: -209px; border: 0px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: bold; font-stretch: normal; font-size: 69px; line-height: normal; font-family: Arial; text-align: center; color: rgb(241, 87, 0); padding: 0px; -webkit-appearance: none; background: none;">';

?>
```

and i have one js file that is i want to refresh and change the velue when it changes with this code:

```
refresh();

function refresh()
{

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "pro.php",
        error: function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        },
        success: function(result) {

            $("#progress-circle").val(result).trigger('change');
        }
    });


    setTimeout(refresh, 1000);
}
```

But when the value change, it don't change in my html, it only update when i refresh the page.

Comment: Please log what `result` actually contains. It might simply not return what you think it should return. Other than that, the code seems to work fine.

Comment: On another note: Why do you include the style in the tag itself, rather than via a stylesheet?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/37z7fmz5/

Answer (score 0):

When using jQuery's `val()` you should only update the value property. It doesn't work if you provide the whole html node.

You can update your php inserting this between `$percent = ...` and your `echo`

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest') {
    // Kein AJAX-Request, der passende Header fehlt
    echo $percent;
    exit;
}
```